# How does Windows Storage Spaces (win server 2016) handle parity with different sized drives?

Tags: windows-server-2016, storage-spaces

When using drives with different sizes in a Synology NAS, there is an option on many models called the SHR which to my understanding is a parity mode that dividces the drives' volumes into smaller chunks that can be parity matched among different drives. This way less space is wasted.

Does the parity mode in Windows Storage Spaces in Windows Server 2016 work similarily? I can't seem to find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

With Storage Spaces, you should be able to create a parity of different size drives, but it will be limited by the size of the smallest drive. Unfortunately, there's no chance to use rest of the storage on a bigger drive to create cross parity, as it would be unavailable.